# Ubuntu 18.04.2 (LTS) gets stuck in a login loop

Tags: 18.04, login, gui

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 (LTS). It was working smoothly for some days. But now I can't login. When I try to get into the desktop by entering the valid password and hit enter button, after 5-6 seconds the screen splashes and the login screen appears again. I can login into my account with the shell by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and get back into the GUI login screen by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> until that appears. I have tried all solutions in the question [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop). But all  failed to login into my account. One answer suggested me to create new user with permission to use the sudo command. With that new account I can login. But when I try to login with the previous account the login loop continues. I need to access that account. An answer suggested me to check the permission of .Xauthority, but it doesn't exists. I have also tried to get into the GUI by executing `startx` command in the shell. This works and appears a GUI on the new account but not on the previous account. Unfortunately I don't get an have an internet connection on Ubuntu. So I can't use apt or apt-get command. But I have a Windows PC with administration rights and internet connection. May something occurred in my home directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch the login display manager from gdm3 to lightdm. LightDM is a more lightweight login display manager than gdm3. Download [lightdm](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/lightdm/download), change directories using `cd` to the directory containing lightdm_1.26.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb file that you downloaded, and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt install ./lightdm_1.26.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb     
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm 
sudo reboot
```

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` will open up a new window allowing you to select lightdm as the default login display manager. Use the arrow keys to select lightdm, press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to put the focus on **<OK>** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then reboot by running `sudo reboot`

If that doesn't work, try booting from Xorg instead of Wayland. Edit `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` with `sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`, uncomment `#WaylandEnable=false` so it is `WaylandEnable=falseand runsudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3 # select lightdm`

You might need to delete .Xauthority (which is located in `/home/your-username/.Xauthority`) if the login loop persists after trying these suggestions. It will be created automatically the next time you reboot.

Answer (score 2):

## Environment

18.04.03 LTS

## Did not work

- Login to terminal (CTL+ALT+F4) and reset password.
- Login to terminal, create a new user and try to login with the new user
- Create empty ~/.bashrc and ~/.profile

## Solution

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt upgrade -y
```

Comment: This answer proved useful. I also installed the NVIDIA graphics drivers using  sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

Comment: sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall Did the trick for me, didn’t need anything else

Answer (score 0):

It is a storage issue.For my case I used used root to login in and deleted some folders in my normal user directory to create space in my disk .Then I logged out .I was successfully able to login into my  normal user session.

Comment: How do you reckon the OP has a storage issue - nothing in the post indicates that? At least, ask for some proof to back up your theory.

Answer (score 0):

My login loop was solved by switching to `Ubuntu on Wayland` on the login page (settings icon on the bottom right).

In my case, I tried every possible suggestion including reinstalling drivers and GUI.